# How to use python-xbee to get remote XBee's DIO data

Tags: python, xbee

I can use `IS` (Input Sample) command to get the DIO (digital I/O) sample data from local XBee correctly. As the document says sample data is a dictionary. But when I use the same command for a remote XBee, what I get is just a hex number.

For example, sending `IS` command from local XBee, I get the dictionary `{'dio-1':False,'dio-2':False}`. But when I send `IS` command to a remote XBee, it returns `{'parameter':'\x01\x00\x06\x00\x00'}`

The XBee manual on Page 46 explains the `'IS'` command. But I'm a little confused about it. Can we use this command to get remote sample data?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the python-xbee library just needs to be updated to parse the Remote AT Response to the `ID` command in the same way it currently does for a Local AT Response.

I haven't looked through the code, but you might be able to contact the [project team](http://code.google.com/p/python-xbee/people/list) about it to see if they can fix it.

Comment: OK.BTW I can't find the mail list on the project page.There are only 3 members

Comment: I think [pmalmsten](http://stackoverflow.com/users/422116/pmalmsten) has a gmail.com account -- look through the source code to find it.  You might also be able to find code in the source to parse local IS responses and make use of it for remote IS responses as well.